# PowerShell Drop Text Before and After String

Tags: powershell, split

I have a PowerShell script that automatically generates a signature for all employees by pulling data from AD and using a docx template that has variables in it and replacing the variables with the strings we pull from AD.

Our AD structure automatically adds some extra data to the end of the address (123 Main Street Floor: 01 Room: 01) but most employees do not have a Floor or Room # so we would like to remove this from the output that is being sent to the signature.

On the same token, our AD structure is now adding +1 to the beginning of all phone numbers (ie. +1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX) and we would like to remove the +1 from all signatures.

any suggestions on how I can pull the string from AD, remove the unwanted content that is before/after the string, and output it as needed to the signature?

I have tried various ways of using split, -split, and replace and cannot get string outputs, only outputs looking like "System.Object[]"

This is what we have for the address:

```
$ADStreetAddress = $ADUser.streetaddress -Replace "Floor.*"

If ($ADStreetAddress -ne '') { 
       $FindText = "StreetAddress"
    $ReplaceText = $ADStreetAddress.ToString()
   }
   Else {
    $FindText = "StreetAddress"
    $ReplaceText = $DefaultAddress
    }
```

After the script above, if I type in $ADStreetaddress it gives me the output I want, but when I try to run the script replacing the text, it replaces the text with System.Output[] instead of the actual string we are trying to output.  Thank you all in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the +1 I would use `trim()`

```
$TheirPhone.trim("+1 ")
```

To keep everything before Floor. Try using:

```
$TheirAddress.substring(0,$TheirAddress.IndexOf('Floor'))
```

Comment: Thanks Nixphoe! The trim worked but for the address I get the following when trying IndexOf:


Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length"
At line:1 char:1
+ $ADStreetAddress = $ADStreetAddress.substring(0,$ADStreetAddress.Inde ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: What's the output of `$ADStreetAddress` and `$ADStreetAddress | gm`

Comment: $ADStreetAddress returns:
123 Main Street Floor: 01 Room: 01

Comment: $ADStreetAddress | gm returns: TypeName: System.String

Comment: What does `$ADUser.streetaddress.IndexOf('Floor')` give you? If you put that number in the second number, what do you get?
`$ADUser.streetaddress.SubString(0,15)`

Comment: Weird, $ADUser.streetaddress.IndexOf('Floor') is giving me a -1 even though "Floor" does exist when typing $ADStreetaddress

Comment: How are you generating $ADStreetaddress?

Comment: The script is pulling it from Active Directory based on the user that is logged in.

Comment: It might be simpler to use native powershell rather than calling .net. Try:
`$ADUser = get-aduser $UserName -Properties streetaddress
$ADStreetAddress = $ADUser.StreetAddress`

Comment: I think I got it.  Looks like AD might have been outputing in a variable value so I used | Out-String and then used the IndexOf line you mentioned and it worked! Thank you so much for your time Nixphoe! I truly appreciate it!!

Comment: Great to hear @DanielS